# TIdFTP Error Handling in Delphi (Indy 10)

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy

Can anyone explain to me how to handle errors with `TIdFTP`?

For example, I try to connect as follows ...

```
with IdFTP do
begin
  Username := xxxxx;
  Password := '1000';
  Host := xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
  Port := 21;
  ConnectTimeOut := 5000;
  try
    Connect;
  except
    On E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

If I use the wrong password (as I have deliberately done in the above example to simulate what might happen if a user provides the wrong password), I get the error "Bad sequence of commands".  That tells me nothing about the real problem.  Is there any way to get a meaningful description of the actual error, ie: that the password is incorrect?

Comment: You'll have to catch that particular exception type, not just `Exception`. It's probably the `EIdFTPAUTHException` type in `IdFTP` unit. No time to test/verify though.

Comment: As Jerry said, there is probably a specific error to handle, which indicates what is going on. To start finding out, ShowMessage the ClassName of the exception you get. It is probably not Exception. If you know the class name, you can check for that specific class and react appropriately: `ShowMessageFmt('Error of type %s: %s', [E.ClassName, E.Message]);`.

Comment: `TIdFTP.Connect()` actually does a lot of work internally. Quite a few commands are issued. If you set the `TIdFTP.AutoLogin` property to False, authentication-related commands will not be issued. You can then call `TIdFTP.Login()` manually after `TIdFTP.Connect()` exits, and use a separate `try/except` for it. But, to diagnose more generic errors like "bad sequence of commands", you need to capture the raw FTP commands/responses to know exactly which command failed. You can use a packet sniffer, or assign a `TIdLog...` component to the `TIdFTP.Intercept` property, to capture that traffic.